# Pyttsx3 Changing Voice

Tags: pyttsx

I'm trying to experiment with different voices but can't seem to change the voice. Research gave me this example:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init('espeak')
engine,setProperty('voice', 'english+f1')
engine.setProperty('rate', 175)
engine.say("Hello, what would you like me to do?")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Which gave following error:

```
 File "ttstest.py", line 3, in <module>
    engine,setProperty('voice', 'english+f1')
NameError: name 'setProperty' is not defined
```

If I comment out

```
engine,setProperty('voice', 'english+f1')
```

Program runs fine

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a period instead of a comma between `engine` and `setProperty`?